what is the best way to in powershell for finding only folder in term of time performance
I have an issue, where I have to purge folders,
the name of the folders are most of the time formated and I did a script in powershell to do that.
But I understood that even if I do :
Get-ChildItem -Path $array[2] -Recurse -Directory
the command will check every item in every folder even if that is not a folder, and that is leading to some hours to get every folder path.
how should I do to permit that to perform in term of time ?
here is a part of the script
foreach ($line in Get-Content ".\Exe-Purge-directories.txt") {

    $array = $line.Split("|")
    $deleteType = $array[0]
    $sdate = [int]$array[1] * -1 # nb de jour a retrancher ( nb negatif)
    $expiredDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($sdate) # today + date a retrancher 
    $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $array[2] -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    #the line above is the one taking time  
    $pathException = Get-ChildItem -Path $array[2] -File #-Force #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if ($deleteType.Equals("DateTimeInFolderName")) {
        foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                     if ($folder.Name -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}$')
            # .....


-filter would help

What version of powershell? Roughly how many directories to purge each time? roughly how many files are in those directories? Where are the files stored (local disk, network disk etc)?

To make it go faster you need to restrict what your asking powershell to fetch. Its not very fast with very large numbers of files/directories. Read  Get-ChildItem docs for some options - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem#parameters -  -filter as @js2010 is a good start, but generally being more specific is better for performance so read up on -Attributes ,-Depth  & -Exclude and see if you can apply them to your situation. And use measure-command to test your code/changes!

What does your input file look like? Is it in fact a csv file with pipe symbols (|) as separator characters?

You might create your own recursive function (or better use a Stack, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78354655/1701026) to crawl through all the folders. For complete answer, on how to do that, I recommend you set up a working (but poor performing) [mcve] of what you trying to achieve.

@MisterSmith I'm on 5.1
folders are organized like that : folder named YYYY-MM and in each of this folder a folder per day named DD, in our most used days folder it may have more than 50k files each days, usually small files
I think the best idea, would be to not enter into the day folder, but I can't anticipate the depht of the YYYY-MM folder. as I want to purge by date, I just have to concatenate both folder to know if I have to delete it
I'll check on your suggestion when I can.
thanks a lot !

thanks to your advices, I have done a recursive function.
here it is, I know it's not perfect, but if someone gets to have the same problem, here what worked for me as my folders name have formatted name
function Recursive-FolderSearch {
param (
    [string[]]$Paths,  
    [string]$expiredDate  
)

foreach ($Path in $Paths) {
    
    if ((Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) -and (Split-Path $Path -Leaf) -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}$') {
        
        $folderDays = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Attributes Directory
        foreach ($folderDay in $folderDays) {
            if ($folderDay.Name -match '^\d{2}$') {# if folder respect format DD
                # concat folder AAAA-MM and folder format DD to get complete date
                $dateDossier = [datetime]::ParseExact("$(Split-Path $Path -Leaf)-$($folderDay.Name)", "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
                if ($dateDossier -lt $expiredDate) { #compare folder date with actual date 
                # then suppress folder if older than requested
                    Remove-Item -Path $folderDay.FullName -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                }
            }
        }
        #Supprimer le dossier AAAA-MM s'il est vide
        if (-not (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  )) { #| Where-Object { $_. PSIsContainer -eq $true }
            Remove-Item -Path $Path -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    
    } 
    elseif (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {
        $subDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Attributes Directory -Force

        foreach ($subDir in $subDirs) {
            Recursive-FolderSearch -Paths $subDir.FullName $expiredDate
        }
    } 
}

}

Even the help says you can use recurse and the directory switch together. However, this is kind of interesting. . .
Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory -Recurse }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 37
Ticks             : 378159
TotalDays         : 4.37684027777778E-07
TotalHours        : 1.05044166666667E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.000630265
TotalSeconds      : 0.0378159
TotalMilliseconds : 37.8159

Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 40
Ticks             : 409181
TotalDays         : 4.7358912037037E-07
TotalHours        : 1.13661388888889E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.000681968333333333
TotalSeconds      : 0.0409181
TotalMilliseconds : 40.9181

The one with the Directory switch does take a bit longer. What happens if YOU try the "-Attributes Directory" parameter on your setup?

HEllo !
thanks for the update, indeed it is interesting, I'll try, but today, the script run on more than 3 days, and often crash because of memory.. But i'll definitivly take this into account I keep you informed,
I'm on a version of recursive function

The 2 ways that I know of are by parameter and by filter
Get-ChildItem has a parameter named "-Directory" that should only list directories. "dir /ad" in the DOS days.
The second and slightly slower option is to pipe Get-ChildItem to Where-Object with the filter for "PSIsContainer"
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}


Hello @Vern Anderson,
indeed, I put the parameters -Directory,
but after checking, even with this it will check every "item" to check if it is a file or a directory and that is why it take so much time

The code in the question already uses -Directory while looking for better performance; mentioning an even slower alternative seems counterproductive.
